# Is there a way to create an Interface from an existing class?

Tags: visual-studio, interface

I know it was possible in older versions, but cannot find it in Visual Studio 2015 Community.

Any tips?

Comment: I'm having the same issue but the only extract option I have is "Extract Class" I have a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the class and go to menu Edit - Refactor - Extract Interface.

Comment: Doh! Thanks for the quick answer.